# Highlight <p:inputText> if serverside validation get failed In PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to highlight an `p:inputText` (used to hold an email address) if this value doesn't match the value which came from the database. Here is my java code :

```
private UIInput gUiInputemailAdd;  //global variable

public void validateCredentials(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    UIComponent components = event.getComponent();
    UIInput uiInputemailAdd = (UIInput) components.findComponent("emailAdd");//ID of textbox
    gUiInputemailAdd = uiInputemailAdd;
    // uiInputemailAdd.setValid(false);//works fine here(it highlights this particular textBox)
}

public boolean forgotPasswordValidator(UserDetailTO userDetailTO)
        throws MessagingException {
    if (!gEmailAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(userDetailTO.getEmailAddress())) {
        System.out.println(gUiInputemailAdd.getValue().toString()); //works fine and print value
        gUiInputemailAdd.setValid(false);//doesn't work here
    }
}
```

Xhtml code:-

```xml
<p:outputLabel for="emailAdd" value="EmilAddresss" />
<p:inputText value="#{loginTo.emailAddress}" id="emailAdd"/>
```

Please help me on this I have been stuck here for so long.

Comment: Please post your component's markup as well. First guess is that you forgot to add ajax update for the component

Comment: ok iam about to paste xhtml code. please have look into it

Comment: What is the Scope of your backing bean?